# Question about |= in c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

What means |= in c#?

Example:

```
int a= 0;
int b = a |= 5;
```

I can't find any hints for this.

Comment: Its the OR operator: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5f1zzaw.aspx

Answer (score 12, accepted):

the OR assignment operator.

full explanation is here.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5f1zzaw(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: That's how i understood this:
9 - 1001
0 - 0000
9 OR 0 = 1001

Comment: Thanks, it explain me everything ;)

Answer (score 4):

|= is the OR assignment operator.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5f1zzaw.aspx

Answer (score 4):

"|" is a bitwise OR operator. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxszd0kx(v=vs.71).aspx

So,

```
a |= 5;
```

is the same as

```
a = a | 5;
```

Comment: It is bitwise for integer operands, and logical OR for bool operands

Answer (score 3):

This is in the MSDN Library under operators for c#

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5f1zzaw.aspx

Answer (score 2):

It is an assignment operator that performs a bitwise logical OR on integral operands and a logical OR on bool operands.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5f1zzaw(v=VS.100).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Bitwise or.

Your snippet becomes.

```
int a = 0;
int b;
a = a | 5;
b = a;
```

In the end, a = b = 5