# C# Suggestion Convert to '|=' expression

Tags: c#, monodevelop, xamarin-studio

Okay, I apologize if this is a stupid question but I can't get a google search to find what I'm looking for and I'm not sure where else to turn. I was writing some C# code and have a simple if statement looking at 2 booleans.

```
if(a && !b)
    do something
```

I'm using MonoDevelop or Xamarin Studio or whatever it's called and it underlined the if in blue and the popup says: **Suggestion: Convert to '|=' expression**. I'm not an inexperienced programmer but I don't think I've ever seen **|=** before and I have no idea what that means or what this suggestion is suggesting, if it's actually even valid at all. Anyone willing to clue me in? Thanks for any help.

**Editing in some more because others asked**
The real code is not much more than that. It's essentially

```
if(a && !b)
    c = true;
```

Not quite sure how I could make the bitwise shortcut operator work here since I'm using three different variables, but bitwise operations are a huge lacking point of my abilities. But that is exactly what the suggestion is saying on the underlined if.

Comment: [SymbolHound is your friend](http://symbolhound.com/?q=what+is+|%3D)

Comment: I’m having a hard time believing this. Can you post the whole `if`, including the `do something` part?

Comment: SymbolHound? Thanks. Hadn't heard of it but looks like it will be very helpful.

Comment: It is like += or -=.

Comment: if your only question is "what is this" it should be closed as a duplicate for instance to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5492747/what-is-the-operator-how-can-i-implement-this-in-c) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7041028/question-about-in-c-sharp) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6942477/what-does-single-pipe-equal-and-single-ampersand-equal-mean-in-c-sharp). If your question is about why you get a suggestion to convert it, it might need some editing to highlight this.

Comment: That's fine, it can be closed. I can't seem to turn up anything when searching on |= though so would love to know how others are doing that.

Comment: well, I did give you the symbolhound suggestion :) however, I still think there are people here who are wondering why you got that suggestion (including me). It might be a valid question if you add details regarding what it wanted to convert.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. What does performing the conversion convert it into?

Comment: I'm not able to. Monodevelop just shows it as a text bubble when I highlight the underline. It's not actually providing me the ability to change the code for me as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bitwise OR and assignment. `a |= b` is equivalent to `a = a | b`.

Comment: this is only answering part of the question - OP is also asking why he gets a suggestion to convert the existing expression.

Comment: @Default That would require more detail about the exact statement used.

Comment: No, that's what I was asking. And of course, I don't know why I didn't think of bitwise operators. I deal so rarely with them that I just never think about them. Stupid question, as I said. Thanks very much for the help. I'll mark your answer as accepted when it lets me in 10 minutes. Though perhaps a mod will prefer to just delete this.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at code that handles this case for more details.

MonoDevelop(and almost all Xamarin Studio(except mobile AddIns)) is open source.

https://github.com/icsharpcode/NRefactory/blob/master/ICSharpCode.NRefactory.CSharp.Refactoring/CodeIssues/Synced/PracticesAndImprovements/ConvertIfToOrExpressionIssue.cs